# Can we get 2 types of labels from fedex API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

Can we get 2 types of  labels from fedex API?

We are connecting to fedex API in ruby on rails . But we can get one label in either .pdf or .pcx format . How can we get both types of label in single rate request ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  You can only receive one image type back within the ship response.

FedEx supports either PNG or PDF images for laser/inkjet printers and Zebra, Eltron or Unimark for thermal printers.